# Auto generated key in mysql jdbc

Tags: java, mysql

i am not getting the auto generated key from mysql

```
String query="insert into course(subject,board,standard,course_code)values(?,?,?,?)";
            st1 = con.prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            st1.setString(1, sub);
            st1.setString(2, board);
            st1.setString(3, std);
            st1.setString(4, course);

            rs1 = st1.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs1.next()){
                cid=rs1.getInt(1);
            }
            System.out.println("2>>>>>>>>" + cid+" "+rs1);
```

output:

```
2>>>>>>>>0 com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@1b04d3d
```

Answer (score 2):

Write `resultset.executeQuery` and then call `getGeneratedKey`

Comment: This is tutorial:Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
stmt.execute(
    "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (C11) VALUES (1)",
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

Comment: You need to write rs.executeQuery  and then call ResultSet rs1 = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

Comment: I got the answer by using this..st1.executeUpdate();